# rails additional params to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I want to pass a value which the model does not have

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= form_for(@car) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name, "Add New Tags:" %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :additional_parms, value: 'some_value' %>
      <%= f.submit "Add Car",:id => 'tag_btn', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I am using hidden field to the add the value the to params
but when I look at the log, the additional_params is not in the params

Comment: Can you post your log? It should be there.

Comment: what you got in params?

Comment: Perhaps just a typo? You have `additional_parms` instead of `additional_params` in your `hidden_field_tag`. But if you need to pass this param to the model, the Anthony's answer is correct.

Comment: thanks for the input guys, I was trying to access the addtional_params from car_params...and realized that it is located in params[:additional_params]..

Comment: I used to do the same until some users started snooping through the page HTML, messing with variables and so on (I was building a financial-type app) so...it wasn't a good idea. Then again I at one point I was computing some values with JS and populating a hidden field, not all browsers were passing the same values. So... I stopped doing this at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`<%= f.hidden_field :additional_params, value: 'some_value' %>`

Note that you'll need to add this as a virtual field in the model via `attr_acessor` and whitelist the parameter the controller:

**Model**

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base

   attr_accessor :additional_params
   ...
```

**Controller:**

```
def car_params
  params.require(:car).permit( ..., :additional_params)
end
```